# Why does the MPAA allow IMDB to reveal whole synopses of recent movies?

Tags: imdb

Yesterday I was shocked when I saw synopsis of a recently released movie: Finding Dory (2016). It was quite elaborated & you don't need to go to the actual movie for visuals. You will experience images move in front of you if you read synopsis of any movie in IMDB.

Why does MPAA allow IMDB to reveal whole synopsis of recent movies?

Comment: Um... Because that's not what the MPAA does. Why do you think that the MPAA... or anyone, for that matter, would be able to tell IMDb what not to include as far as synopsis goes? There's no group that bans spoilers from the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MPAA has no control over what people write about a film.

They can prevent piracy (copyright infringement) of films and they rate all of the films... but that's it.

They can't tell companies like IMDb or resources like Wikipedia what they can and can not write.

In the case of a script or if there were an "official" plot synopsis, they could prevent someone from duplicating that but an originally-written article telling the basic plot of a film or what a reviewer writes about that film is not something they can tell people not to write about.